# How can I iterate over the components of any JComponent?

Tags: java, swing

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public static AbstractButton findButtonInContainerByText(String text, JComponent container){
    for(Component component : container.getComponents()){
        if(!(component instanceof AbstractButton))
            continue;
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) component;
        if(button.getText().equals(text))
            return button;
    }
    throw new ItemNotFoundException("There is no button with the text '" + text + "' in the container " + container + ".");
}
```

Problem is, this doesn't work properly with `JMenu`s. That's because for some reason you can't just call `getComponents()` on them and get all of the components, you have to call `getMenuComponents()`. And obviously I don't want to do type checking in this method for all kinds of special cases.

Is there a way to iterate correctly over the components inside any kind of `JComponent`?

*As a side note*: In your opinion is there a reason for this API design decision? `JMenu#getComponents()` is deceiving since this isn't what it does. Is there a reason for this problem?

Comment: The way `JMenu` is coded, it's the underlying `JPopupMenu` that holds the components, not the `JMenu` itself. See [the code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JMenu.java) . Maybe just to make sure `getComponents` returns the actual child of a `JComponent`... then why the `JPopupMenu` isn't there... Gotta love Java.

Comment: Take a look at the [class hieratchy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html). The menus and menu items are all `JComponents`. Maybe you aren't traversing the components incorrectly. `getComponents()` will only get direct children, not those contained by those children. You need to do some recursive searching. Also maybe you are traversing the wrong component. The menu mar is contained in the root pane, actually inside a the layered pane of the root pane. Post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see how you're doing this.

Comment: Also see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau The reason `JPopupMenu` isn't returned by `getComponents()` is because it isn't a child component contained within the `JMenu` - it's a separate (possibly top level) component launched when the `JMenu` is clicked.  It's like if a `JButton` launches a `JDialog` when it's clicked, the `JDialog` wouldn't be considered a "child" of the `JButton` either.

Comment: @Nate I find it fits as a child, that `JPopupMenu` can only be created by the `JMenu` it will contain... which leads to the contained menu containing its container... To be a child or not to be?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `Container#getComponents()` returns an array only of the immediate components, not their children.

Since weird stuff is going on in `JMenu`, its 'components' aren't really it's immediate components, so they are regarded as sub-components.

So I searched online and found [a method to recursively get all components of a `Container`, including sub-children](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/GetAllComponentsinacontainer.htm).

Haven't tested it yet, should work.

EDIT: Nope, still doesn't work on a `JMenu`.